# Atlas in CDP 7.0.3: Can not find the specified config set: vertex_index

Tags: solr, cloudera, apache-atlas

I added Atlas in my CDP cluster, and find can't connect the web UI.

In the application.log, I found the error: Can not find the specified config set: vertex_index.

I followed the instruction in the following links, but still couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-18368

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Atlas-UI-not-available-Service-Unavailable/td-p/132435

Here is the application.log:

```
                              Atlas Server (STARTUP)

 

project.name: apache-atlas

project.description: Metadata Management and Data Governance Platform over Hadoop

build.user: jenkins

build.epoch: 1574150696506

project.version: 2.0.0.7.0.3.0-79

build.version: 2.0.0.7.0.3.0-79

vc.revision: cbb309de67ee0215efa0763f03c2f32f40f1d8f3

vc.source.url: scm:git:git://git.apache.org/atlas.git/atlas-webapp

######################################################################################## (Atlas:215)

2020-04-21 16:41:34,562 INFO  - [main:] ~ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (Atlas:216)

2020-04-21 16:41:34,562 INFO  - [main:] ~ Server starting with TLS ? false on port 31000 (Atlas:217)

2020-04-21 16:41:34,562 INFO  - [main:] ~ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< (Atlas:218)

2020-04-21 16:41:35,236 INFO  - [main:] ~ No authentication method configured.  Defaulting to simple authentication (LoginProcessor:102)

2020-04-21 16:41:35,315 WARN  - [main:] ~ Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable (NativeCodeLoader:60)

2020-04-21 16:41:35,397 INFO  - [main:] ~ Logged in user atlas (auth:SIMPLE) (LoginProcessor:77)

2020-04-21 16:41:36,202 INFO  - [main:] ~ Not running setup per configuration atlas.server.run.setup.on.start. (SetupSteps$SetupRequired:189)

2020-04-21 16:41:38,552 WARN  - [main:] ~ given scan urls are empty. set urls in the configuration (Reflections:181)

2020-04-21 16:41:38,635 WARN  - [main:] ~ org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Krb5HttpClientBuilder is configured without specifying system property 'java.security.auth.login.config' (Krb5HttpClientBuilder:142)

2020-04-21 16:41:39,523 INFO  - [main:] ~ ==> KafkaNotification() (KafkaNotification:105)

2020-04-21 16:41:39,524 INFO  - [main:] ~ <== KafkaNotification() (KafkaNotification:137)

2020-04-21 16:41:39,562 INFO  - [main:] ~ Creating indexes for graph. (GraphBackedSearchIndexer:286)

2020-04-21 16:41:40,629 INFO  - [main:] ~ Created index : vertex_index (GraphBackedSearchIndexer:291)

2020-04-21 16:41:40,645 INFO  - [main:] ~ Created index : edge_index (GraphBackedSearchIndexer:297)

2020-04-21 16:41:40,655 INFO  - [main:] ~ Created index : fulltext_index (GraphBackedSearchIndexer:303)

2020-04-21 16:41:40,775 ERROR - [main:] ~ GraphBackedSearchIndexer.initialize() failed (GraphBackedSearchIndexer:353)

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://xxx:8983/solr: Can not find the specified config set: vertex_index

at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:627)

at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:253)

at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:242)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to create the `vertex_index`, `edge_index`, `fulltext_index` in Solr.

Create 3 collections in Solr, for me it works.